# Junit tests on android studio invokes Device chooser dialog

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing

I am trying to run a junit test on one of my class method in my app module but everytime I run the test, **a device chooser dialog is invoked** INSTEAD of running and printing test results on my console

Note: I have also changed **Test Artifact** value to Unit Tests in Build Variants window

this is my class

```
public class ManTest{

    @Test
    public void testAddData(){
        //code here
        System.out.println("should print data on the console");
    }
}
```

this class location is  **app/src/test/java/me.app/ManTest.java**

This is my app.gradle

```
repositories(){
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```

Where am I doing wrong or what am I missing in my test setup?

Comment: Right click on your test class (or test package) and click `Create ManTest...`. Then run it.

Comment: @bigdestroyer   there is nothing like create manTest when i right click it

Comment: Right click on your `ManTest.java`. Option `Create ManTest...` should be available. This will create a test run configuration. Then just run it and tests inside the class will be executed.

Comment: @bigdestroyer i saw `create all Tests` option when i right clicked my java folder which contain `me.app/ManTest.java`. even when i click ok on that options nothing changes. when i go to **Run> Edit Config** and click on my ManTest which is under **Android Tests** . on the right under **Target Device**, i see **show chooser dialog** as the selected option. but i can't see a better option beside it that allows running on the console

Comment: After `Create all Tests`, don't change run configuration. Use "All tests" run configuration, in order to run all test under package.

Comment: @bigdestroyer  nothing happens!. i had to click **Run `ManTest` with Coverage** for it to work